# Нужно передать параметры одного класса другому

Tags: python, ооп, классы

как передать параметры из класса Vetrina: self.item_price,self.item_name,self.item_am, классу User.Buyer

```
class Vitrina:
def __init__(self,name,am,price):
    self.item_name=name
    self.item_am=am
    self.item_price=price
    print(self.item_name,' amount ',self.item_am,' price',self.item_price)
def popolnenie(self,a,b):
    if self.item_name == a:
        self.item_am+=b
        print(self.item_name,' amount ',self.item_am)

class User:
class Buyer():
    def __init__(self,addr,ballance):

        self.addr=addr
        self.ballance=ballance
        print('addr is ',self.addr,'your ballance is',self.ballance)
    def popolnenie(self,a):
        self.ballance += a
        print('your ballance is',self.ballance)
    def buy(self,name,am):
        if self.ballance>=self.item_am*self.item_price:
            if am<=self.item_am and name == self.item_name:
                ballance -= self.item_am* self.item_price
                print('You buy ',name ,' you ballance is',ballance,' your addr is ',self.addr)
            else:
                print('you cant buy it')
        else:
            print('your ballance very smoll to buy ',name)
```

Comment: правильно понимаю, что вы хотите сделать покупателю метод "ознакомиться с витриной", где на вход будет класс витрины?

Comment: @EugeneDennis Мне надо сделать метод покупки товара – метод принимает на вход количество единиц товара и название.

Comment: а причём здесь витрина?

Comment: @EugeneDennis в классе витрина хранится название продукта, его стоимость и кол-во. Все эти данные нужно передать классу User.Buyer.

Comment: в ответе был приведён пример передачи атрибутов между классами, вам не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что всё-таки действительно требуется - передать параметр класса другому классу или параметр экземпляра класса экземпляру другого класса.
Если, всё-таки, нужно именно то, что указано в заголовке вопроса, то может работать такая схема:

```
class c1():
    c1str='blahblah'
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class c2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c2str=c1().c1str

print(c2().c2str)
```

Выведет:

```
blahblah
```